# Extending named range by 1 row

Tags: excel, vba

How can I insert 1 row into namedrange at the end of named range?
Named range should then have 2 rows and rows should be shifted down, however not at the start of the named range, but at the end.
I tried this but doesn't work:

```
ASheet.Range(Me.Name).Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
ASheet.Range(Me.Name).End(xlDown).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

alternative for testing:

```
Range("B17:D17").Name = "test"
Range("test").Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

What I was thinking is if I should insert a row below named range and then extend name range... assuming you can't insert a row inside 1 row named range.

Comment: Please include all the code so that I can duplicate the problem.  e.g. define ASheet, define the range Me.Name, and populate the inserted row.  Please give before/after insert examples of current sheet, and desired sheet.

Comment: So you want to add the row at the very end? If so that requires to rename the named range. If you happy to insert the row at one position above the last row in the named range, it is possible without renaming.

Comment: A named range will grow automatically if you insert a row in the middle of it, but not at the end. It would appear you want to create a `ListObject` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is one of the solutions... but requires renaming named range.

```
Range("B17:D17").Name = "test"
Range("test").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("B17:D18").Name = "test"
```